# Как реализивать подобное

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Стало интересно как заверстать что то подобное.
Нужно использовать инпуты радио

[image]

Comment: с какой конкретно частью возникли проблемы?

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Например так:

```css
.radio-group {
  --size: 20px;
  --bg: #fff;
  --stroke-width: 2px;
  --stroke: #ccc;
  --check-size: 12px;
  --check-fill: #6f9f36;
  --sep-width: 10px;
  --sep-height: 8px;
}
.radio-group input {
  display: none;
}

.radio-group label {
  display: block;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: var(--stroke-width) solid var(--stroke);
  background-color: var(--bg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-group label:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--sep-height) - (var(--stroke-width) * 2) - (var(--stroke-width) / 2));
}

.radio-group label:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: var(--sep-width);
  height: var(--sep-height);
  border-left: var(--stroke-width) solid var(--stroke);
  border-right: var(--stroke-width) solid var(--stroke);
  background-color: var(--bg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(calc(var(--stroke-width) / -2));
  z-index: 1;
}

.radio-group label::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: var(--check-size);
  height: var(--check-size);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: var(--check-fill);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.radio-group input:checked + label::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-group">
  <input id="radio-1" type="radio" name="radio">
  <label for="radio-1"></label>
  <input id="radio-2" type="radio" name="radio">
  <label for="radio-2"></label>
  <input id="radio-3" type="radio" name="radio">
  <label for="radio-3"></label>
  <input id="radio-4" type="radio" name="radio" checked>
  <label for="radio-4"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  accent-color: green;
  clip-path: circle(16px);
  margin: -16px;
}

div {
  display: grid;
  width: min-content;
  border: 8px solid;
  border-color: transparent silver;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: -8px -16px;
}

div:first-child {
  border-top-color: silver;
}

div:last-child {
  border-bottom-color: silver;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  gap: 16px;
  width: min-content;
  margin: 8px;
  border-inline: 9px solid silver;
}

body {
  display: flow-root;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div><input type=radio name=rbtn></div>
  <div><input type=radio name=rbtn></div>
  <div><input type=radio name=rbtn></div>
  <div><input type=radio name=rbtn checked></div>
</section>
```